# CSV leaves a blank row for every entry

Tags: python, csv

This code below works fine, but the data pasted via *csv lib* onto a CSV file leaves a row blank for every entry and I'm struggling to see why.

```
import praw
import configReddit
import csv

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id=configReddit.client_id,
    client_secret=configReddit.client_secret,
    password=configReddit.password,
    user_agent=configReddit.user_agent,
    username=configReddit.username,
)

with open('blockchainstable.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    comment_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for comment in reddit.subreddit("CryptoCurrency").stream.comments():
        print(comment.body)
        comment_writer.writerow([comment.body])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `, newline=''` as in the example in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). E.g.,

```py
with open('blockchainstable.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvfile:
    ...
```